# When does mod->init be assigned

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

When Linux Kernel load new module with insmod, it will invoke

```
finit_module
  do_init_module
    do_one_initcall
```

then the init function defined in module will be invoked.

```c
static noinline int do_init_module(struct module *mod)
{
    int ret = 0;
    struct mod_initfree *freeinit;

    freeinit = kmalloc(sizeof(*freeinit), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!freeinit) {
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto fail;
    }
    freeinit->module_init = mod->init_layout.base;

    /*
     * We want to find out whether @mod uses async during init.  Clear
     * PF_USED_ASYNC.  async_schedule*() will set it.
     */
    current->flags &= ~PF_USED_ASYNC;

    do_mod_ctors(mod);
    /* Start the module */
    if (mod->init != NULL)
        ret = do_one_initcall(mod->init);
...
}
```

But after searching all code of linux kernel, I haven't found the place where does mod->init assigned, could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to find that assignment or initialization? What is the actual and underlying problem you're trying to solve? Or is it just plain curiosity (which is okay, but then please tell us)? Otherwise please ask us directly about the real problem. Perhaps take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, it is just plain curiosity. I am interested with the scenario of how to load the kernel module, so I checked the code, but blocked here.

Comment: I believe the information ends up in the `struct module` compiled into the `.gnu.linkonce.this_module` section of the .ko file. The generated source is in the *modulename*.mod.c file.

Comment: You can also use the `objdump -j .gnu.linkonce.this_module -r modulename.ko` command to see the relocation information for the `struct module` embedded in the `.gnu.linkonce.this_module` section of the .ko file. It should show relocation information for `init_module` and `cleanup_module` if they exist in the module. (Those functions may be created by the `module_init(initfn)` and `module_exit(exitfn)` macro calls.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of `mod->init` and `mod->exit` come from the `struct module __this_module` variable contained in the `.gnu.linkonce.this_module` section of the module's .ko file. The kernel assumes that this variable is at the start of the section, and in fact it is the *only* variable in the section.

The `__this_module` variable is initialized by a C initializer within the *modulename*.mod.c file that is generated during the MODPOST phase of the kernel build process. A typical definition of the `__this_module` variable in a *modulename*.mod.c file looks like this for current kernels:

```
__visible struct module __this_module
__section(.gnu.linkonce.this_module) = {
    .name = KBUILD_MODNAME,
    .init = init_module,
#ifdef CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD
    .exit = cleanup_module,
#endif
    .arch = MODULE_ARCH_INIT,
};
```

The `finit_module` and `init_module` syscall handling functions call `load_module` to do most of the work. `load_module` calls `setup_load_info`, which amongst other things, looks for the `.gnu.linkonce.this_module` section that contains only the `__this_module` variable. A temporary pointer to this is placed in `info->mod` (where `info` points to the `struct load_info` used to hold information for loading the module). `load_module` later calls `layout_and_allocate` which returns a pointer to the `__this_module` variable (actually, a pointer to the `.gnu.linkonce.this_module` section) after it has been copied to its final place in kernel memory by `move_module`. After `load_module` calls `apply_relocations` to perform dynamic linking, `mod->init` and `mod->exit` will have their final values (ignoring modifications by `CONFIG_CFI_CLANG` in kernel 5.13 onwards).

Note that the `__this_module.init` function pointer is always either a pointer to `init_module` or is defaulted to null, and the `__this_module.exit` function pointer is always either a pointer to `cleanup_module` or is defaulted to null. (Most module source codes use the `module_init(initfn)` and `module_exit(exitfn)` macros to create those functions, but they can be defined explicitly.)